# Editting Attribute properties in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to edit the precision of my area attribute in QGIS 2.0. It is currently at 0 but I want to change it to 3. I have not been able to find the answer to this anywhere. Is there a way to edit the properties of an attribute, or do I need to create a new column and plug the data into the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [discussion](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2014-January/025905.html) in QGIS User mailing list, there is no direct way to edit columns type, size or precision in QGIS (because most providers won't allow it anyway).

As you said the solution will be to use field calculator to create a new field with the right precision with the values from the old field (this won't help you much in your specific scenario) or even recalculating the area.

If necessary, you can use the table manager plugin, to delete the old column, and sort the columns so that the new one occupies the "place" of the old one,

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of a way to do this.  I do not believe you would get the output you are looking for, as the precision (decimal) information would not be stored along with the integer based attributes.  I would add a new column and recalculate the area in the field calculator using the following: $area